# Why is "Auto Test Project" missing from the creation wizard? | Qt

Tags: qt-creator

I Want to create a auto test project in my sub project.
The common step is "Select File > New Project > Other Project > Auto Test Project > Choose to create a project with boilerplate code for a Qt test or a Qt Quick test."
But there is no auto test project in Other Project, do I overlook something? Please give me a favor.

[image]

I'm trying to find out if I'm missing some components. So I opened the maintenance tools, but I didn't find the components related to Test.